# Find the minimal polynomial over a field

Tags: group-theory, polynomials, finite-groups, galois-theory

I have two similar questions:

1). Find the minimal polynomial for  $a^{-1}$  (a to the power of minus 1) over $F_3$. $a$ is the root of the polynomial $x^3-x+1$ in $F_3[X]$

*I have used the division algorithm to find an expression for $a$ but I am not sure what to do with $a^{-1}$*

Comment: $a^{-1}$ is defined to be such that $a^{-1}a = aa^{-1} = 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $a\ne0$ is a root of $Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$, then $a^{-1}$ is a root of $A+Bx+Cx^2+Dx^3$.

Therefore, 
since 
the minimal polynomial of $a$ in your example is $f(x)=x^3+0x^2-x+1$,
the minimal polynomial of $a^{-1}$ is $g(x)=1+0x-x^2+x^3=1-x^2+x^3$.

Note that $g(x)=x^3f(1/x)$ and this implies that $g$ is irreducible.

Comment: A useful fact to remember

Comment: In case this is not 100% clear: If $p(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1x+a_0$, then
$$x^np(\frac1x)=a_0x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{n-1}x+a_n.$$